# C# Xamarin Variable to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of names and if I click on one it will open 
ActionSheet Dialogue (`Open`, `Edit`, `Delete`)

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Choose action:", "Cancel", null, "Open", "Edit", "Delete");
switch (action)
{
    case "Open":
        wait Navigation.PushAsync(new NamePageOpen(e.Appointment as Models.Event, Callback));
        break;
    case "Edit":                
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NamePageEdit(e.Appointment as Models.Event, Callback));
        break;
    case "Delete":
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NamePageDelete(e.Appointment as Models.Event, Callback));
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

After action choose it will open one of content page with XAML like:

```
<StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5">
    <Label Text="Name"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Title}"/>

    <Label Text="Detail"/>
    <Editor Text="{Binding Detail}" HeightRequest="100"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I want to add new field `Type` and use some more actions (`Open1`, `Open2`, `Open3`).

```
<Label Text="Type"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding Type}"/>
```

But I want to use the same content page.
Is it possible to get value (1,2,3) in field `Type` which will depend on chosen action in display action sheet?

Hope for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you don't try and reuse pages in this manner.  You might think reusing is a good idea today, but in 3 months time, when this duplication is no longer correct, you will have to split the pages/views/models etc.  Best to do it now and save yourself some headaches down the road.

Comment: Well, I trust your experience